rails docker temp folder permission issue
i'm having an issue with my rails app deployed with docker. Every time app goes through a code using tempfile like (Tempfile.new) it raises an error .
system temporary path is not writable: /tmp
11:00:30 web.1    | /tmp is not writable: /tmp
11:00:30 web.1    | . is not writable: /rails
11:00:30 web.1    | 2024-07-22 11:00:30 +0000 Rack app ("POST /folders/dropzone_import" - (82.64.63.1)): #<ArgumentError: could not find a temporary directory>
ruby "3.0.2"
gem "rails", "~> 7.1.3.1"
on ubuntun 22.04
In have this in my .dockerignore
/log/*
/tmp/*
!/log/.keep
!/tmp/.keep


please add your dockerfile to the question

Thanks @dbugger. Its finally overrided in initializer defaut rails tmp folder
